# Copying content from subject matter expert site to support answer

Tags: discussion

I answered a question today with knowledge I have from experience.  To delve further into the topic I did some research and found a very good article to support my answer and give deeper information to the question.  So, I updated my answer with a link to the article.

I hate broken links so I considered copying the text from the expert's site into my answer with full disclosure that it was his work, not mine - as well as a link back to where I got the text from.  (just in case the link disappears in the future)

Is this OK?  I know links get shared all the time, but is it crossing a line to copy the whole article (few paragraphs) into my answer even if I credit the source with original link?  What is the general rule on the internet for copying and pasting and crediting sources.  How about the stack overflow best practice of the same?

Here is the question/answer for reference.

[In normal cases is there any significant advantages to creating an index that is a partial key of the begining of an existing index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644723/in-normal-cases-is-there-any-significant-advantages-to-creating-an-index-that-is/10644972#10644972)

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the license the original article grants you, it's not really a rule Stack Overflow *can* establish.

In this case, there is no explicit license, so the default copyright rules kick in.  I'm pretty sure copying the whole article is a violation of those rules - the best thing to do would be to paraphrase in your own words what he says, and/or quoting only portions of the text (which will usually fall under a "fair use" rule).

Comment: I took the copied content out and just left the link... as I was doing it - it felt wrong - which is why I asked.  Thanks for the advice.